# GCP Cloudbuild deploy to GKE

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-build

I've create a *cloudbuild.yaml* that deploys my Helm application on a GKE cluster.
After connecting to the cluster I run a simple `kubectl get pods -A` and all works,
but when I run a `helm list -A` i got this error

```
Get "https://1.2.3.4/version": getting credentials: exec: executable gke-gcloud-auth-plugin not found
It looks like you are trying to use a client-go credential plugin that is not installed.
```

I've even tryed to add a step that shows the *kubeconfig* file and I can see the field `command: gke-gcloud-auth-plugin`

This is my *cloudbuild.yaml* file

```yaml
  - id: 'kubectl-info'
    name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/kubectl'
    args: ['cluster-info']
    waitFor: ['-']
    env:
      - KUBECONFIG=/builder/home/.kube/config
      - CLOUDSDK_COMPUTE_REGION=$_DEFAULT_REGION
      - CLOUDSDK_CONTAINER_CLUSTER=$_GKE_NAME
      - USE_GKE_GCLOUD_AUTH_PLUGIN=True
  
  
  - id: 'helm-status'
    name: 'alpine/helm:3.11.2'
    args: ['list', '-A']
    waitFor: ['kubectl-info'],
    env:
      - KUBECONFIG=/builder/home/.kube/config
      - USE_GKE_GCLOUD_AUTH_PLUGIN=True
```

Comment: Can you run the command **gcloud components install gke-gcloud-auth-plugin**. Refer to [Changes to kubectl authentication coming in GKE v1.26](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/containers-kubernetes/kubectl-auth-changes-in-gke).

Comment: I've changed the image to `gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/cloud-sdk` that contains the **auth-plugin** but the error  persists

Comment: Do you have an image where both Helm and gke-gcloud-auth-plugin are installed? Then you can use that image to run the Helm commands. Otherwise, you need to install gcloud, gke-gcloud-auth-plugin and then run the Helm commands in the same step.

Comment: You can rebuild this: [https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-builders-community/tree/master/helm](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-builders-community/tree/master/helm) check the gcloud version present on CloudBuild worker does not have the plugin, make sure you are pulling the latest one that has it by adding --pull to the steps of that build.

Comment: thanks @VeeraNagireddy your solution works perfectly. If you want you can write the answer so I can mark it as correct.

Comment: Hello @ **Hiimjack** glad to hear that. Same posted as an answer, feel free to upvote and mark the answer as accepted for greater visibility for community members.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check do you have an image where both **Helm** and **gke-gcloud-auth-plugin** are installed? Then you can use that image to run the helm commands. Otherwise, you need to install `gcloud`, `gke-gcloud-auth-plugin` and then run the Helm commands in the same step.

You can refer to rebuild this: [Using helm tool builder with Google Container Engine](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-builders-community/tree/master/helm) check the gcloud version present on CloudBuild worker does not have the plugin, make sure you are pulling the latest one that has it by adding `--pull` to the steps of that build.